# convert query to object using LINQ TO SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm Working with LINQ TO SQL in C# to connect to SQL Database

and I have a table on DataBase called `Person` which holds information about persons and have the following fields `Person_Id`, `First_Name`,`Last_Name`,`Email`,`Password`

I have the following query which returns one row if there is matched :

```
LINQDataContext data = new LINQDataContext();
            var query = from a in data.Persons
                        where a.Email == "Any Email String"
                        select a;
```

my question is how to convert the `query` to an instance of Equivalent class which define is :

```
class Person
{
    public int person_id;
    public string First_Name;
    public string Last_Name;
    public string E_mail;
    public string Password;
    public Person() { }
}
```

Comment: how about `var person = query.FirstOrDefault()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
Person query = (from a in data.Persons
            where a.Email == "Any Email String"
            select new Person { person_Id = a.Id, and so on }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks for you,but I want to initialize it to a Person Type not a var and use this reference as return value for a function,  how to do that ??

Comment: In my answer `var` will be `Person` (var is just a keyword to make compiler discover type by itself). You can change var to Person explicitly and it will work just fine (see my edit)

Answer (score 2):

I will do it something like :

```
var query = (from a in data.Persons
            where a.Email == "Unique Email String"
            select new Person { person_Id = a.Id, etc etc });

//By using this code, you can add more conditions on query as well..

//Now the database hit will be made
var person = query.FirstOrDefault();
```